# Proof verification: uniqueness of empty set

Tags: proof-verification, elementary-set-theory, alternative-proof

My question doesn't concern the standard-proof of the uniqueness of the empty set, which uses the lemma that the empty set is a subset of every set. My question concerns an alternate proof that I made before reading the standard one, and which now seams wrong, but I can't find my mistake. Can someone point me in the right direction?

My proof goes as follows:

Let us assume for contradiction that the empty set is not unique. This means that there is another empty set, let's call it $\varnothing'$, for which $ \varnothing' \neq \varnothing $. By the axiom of extensionality we have the following $\varnothing = \varnothing' :\iff \forall x: x \in \varnothing' \leftrightarrow 
x \in \varnothing $, which implies $\varnothing \neq \varnothing' \iff 
\exists x: 
\neg (x \in \varnothing' \leftrightarrow 
x \in \varnothing)$. 
This is equivalent to $ 
(x \in \varnothing' \land x \notin \varnothing) 
\lor 
(x \notin \varnothing' \land x \in \varnothing)
$
. But this is never true, because the empty set (by definition) doesn’t contain any elements. Hence, the empty set is unique.

---

I have read [the following question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/972253/proving-that-the-empty-set-is-unique). My question doesn't only concern the correctness of my proof but also the difference between my proof and the standard one. If my proof is right, then I don't see why one should use the "standard" proof, which uses another lemma, instead of just applying the axiom of extensionality.

Comment: How does it follow from the equality of sets that there exists $x\in\emptyset'$ with $x\notin\emptyset$?

Comment: Correct........ The proof relies on the [Extensionality axiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_extensionality).

Comment: Phrasing the proof as a proof by contradiction is a detour. You can just apply the axiom of extensionality _directly_, since if $A$ and $B$ are empty sets, then $x\in A$ and $x\in B$ are both _always false_ and therefore surely equivalent. Since $\forall x(x\in A \leftrightarrow x \in B)$ the axiom of extensionality _explicitly_ tells you $A=B$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA you mean my proof is correct? Then why isn't this the "standard" proof. It seams way easier since it doesn't rely on other lemmas or anything.

Comment: Why do you think that the "standard proof through the lemma that the empty set is a subset of every set" is different ? The standard proof is $A=B \text { iff } A \subseteq B \text { and } B \subseteq A$ that means (unpacking the def) : $A=B \text { iff } \forall x (x \in A \leftrightarrow x \in B)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof is correct, but it is not immediately clear that

$$\emptyset\neq\emptyset' \implies \exists x\in\emptyset':x\notin\emptyset.$$

I would expand on why that is the case. Indeed, $\emptyset\neq\emptyset'$ means $\neg(\emptyset\subseteq\emptyset'\land\emptyset'\subseteq\emptyset)$, i.e., there exists $x\in\emptyset$ such that $x\notin\emptyset'$ or there exists $x\in\emptyset'$ such that $x\notin\emptyset$. The former is a contradiction ($x\in\emptyset$), so the latter must be the case.

Then the proof continues as you did.

---

It is not the "standard" proof because the statement follows immediately by the definition of equality of sets (the so-called [extensionality axiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_extensionality)). Two sets are equal if they have the same elements, which is vacuously true if we have two empty sets $\emptyset$ and $\emptyset'$.